# Laravel - Bootstrap 4 Not working correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 for my laravel project but for some reason its not working correctly, I'm trying to setup a post like this:
One column for the profile picture which is `col-md-1` and 11 columns for the rest of the post which is `col-md-11` But for some reason it turns out like this [image]

Instead of this: [image]

How is this possible? I have the same issue with another page, My setup looks like this

```
<div class="container first-container">
    <div class="row" id="showEffect">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12" style="border-right: 1px solid #f1f0f0">
            <h2 class="fw-3">Alle vragen</h2><br>
            <div class="row">
                @foreach($posts as $post)
                    <div class="card" style="border: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f0f0">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="{!! asset('images/placeholder.png') !!}" class="rounded-circle" width="50">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11">
                                <a href="{{ $post->path() }}">
                                    <h5 class="mb-0">{{ $post->title }}</h5>
                                </a>
                                <small>
                                    <span>Kanaal</span> • {{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }} door
                                    <a href="">
                                        <span>{{ $post->user->username }}</span>
                                    </a>
                                </small>
                                <p class="mb-0 mt-2">{{ $post->text }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            test
        </div>

    </div>


</div>
```

For some reason the last `col-md-3` at the buttom is supposed to display next to the `col-md-9` but instead its at the buttom of the page. My bootstrap 4 implementation is defeitly working, I can notice in the colour of the buttons. But what is cauusing this? Thanks in advance!

PS: Here is a gif of the elements https://i.stack.imgur.com/59m7W.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say what exactly is going on without seeing the CSS rules that may be in place, but try adding the "row" class to the parent of the "col-md-1" and "col-md-11":

```
<div class="row card-body">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

See docs [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)